# "They serve as means of" vs "They serve as a means of"

Tags: grammar

I made a "mistake":

> The blueprints serve as means of recreating the design.

I meant to write:

> The blueprints serve as **a** means of recreating the design.

Means is a plural noun, which can be treated as singular or plural. So perhaps both are equally correct, even though the first sounds strange to my ear.

What are your thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: It's not a big deal and it could well be that nobody notices. For me, although there there many be many blueprints, they are serving together as one means of recreating the design, so I think the version with *a* is better.